# Struggling with XPath expression for Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

Below, there is the part of some html page (all names of the parameters are in russian). It has the main class and two inner classes. The detailed html-code:

```
    <div class="obj-params">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col" style="min-width:50%;">
                      <p>
                         <b>Param1_name</b>" Param1_value"</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param2_name</strong>" Param2_value</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param3_name</strong>" Param3_value"</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col">
                    <p>
                       <b>Param4_name</b>Param4_value</p>
                <div class="inline-popup popup-hor left">
                   <b>Param5_name</b>
                      <a target="_blank" href="link">Param5_value</a></div></div>
```

I would like to extract the `Param%d_value`'s values. How can I do it using XPath?

I have tried the following expressions:

```
//div[@class="inline-popup popup-hor left"]/a/text() #extract correctly the name of the link
```

However, this expression forms me a list of all `Param%d_value` instead of putting them in organized order:

```
//div[@class="obj-params"]/div[@class="obj-params-col"]/p/text()
```

The question is - how can I construct (per each param_value) XPath expression ? E.x. when I use the following XPath expression

`//div[@class="obj-params"]//div[@class="obj-params-col"]/p/child::text()`

```
['Param1_value, Param2_value, Param3_value, Param1_value, Param2_value, Param3_value, Param1_value, Param2_value, Param3_value']
```

what I need to get is the following:

```
XPath_expression_to_extract_only_Param1_value:

['Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value, Param1_value']  


XPath_expression_to_extract_only_Param2_value:

['Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value, Param2_value']


XPath_expression_to_extract_only_Param3_value:

['Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value, Param3_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `child::text()` to get the text nodes out of the `div` with `obj-params-col` class:

```
//div[@class="obj-params"]//div[@class="obj-params-col"]/p/child::text()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//div[@class="obj-params"]//div[@class="obj-params-col"]/p/child::text()'
" Param1_value"
" Param2_value
" Param3_value"
```

UPDATE:

If you need to get param value by param name, use:

```
//*[text()="Param1_name"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: Is it possible to construct different Xpath expressions for Param1_value, Param2_value and Param3_value? I.e. smth like this: {/div[@class="obj-params"]//div[@class="obj-params-col"]/p/child::text()}

Comment: @mr.M why? It is because you need all of the param values? (from param1 to param5)

Comment: I would like to use this approach because I store each scraped data in the dictionary where the key is the param_name and value is the list of the all param values that are met in the given web-page. I don't want to change this approach.

Comment: @mr.M sorry, still not getting. You have a list of param names and you would like to get a value for each param name?

Comment: Please, see the edited post to understand my question.

Comment: @mr.M thanks, check the update. If this is what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
sel.xpath('//*[contains(./text(),"Param1_name")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
sel.xpath('//*[contains(./text(),"Param2_name")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
sel.xpath('//*[contains(./text(),"Param3_name")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
```