# How can I use non-ASCII characters?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, non-ascii-characters

I am using **Scrapy** and **XPath** to parse web-site in Russian language.

In this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524951/struggling-with-xpath-expression-for-scrapy), [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) suggested me how to construct the xpath expression to get the values. However, I don't understand how can I handle the case when the **Param1_name** is in Russian?

Here is the xpath expression:

```
//*[text()="Param1_name_in_russian"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Html snippet:

```
<div class="obj-params">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col" style="min-width:50%;">
                      <p>
                         <b>Param1_name_in_russian</b>" Param1_value"</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param2_name_in_russian</strong>" Param2_value</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param3_name_in_russian</strong>" Param3_value"</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col">
                    <p>
                       <b>Param4_name_in_russian</b>Param4_value</p>
                <div class="inline-popup popup-hor left">
                   <b>Param5_name</b>
                      <a target="_blank" href="link">Param5_value</a></div></div>
```

**EDITED based on comments**

I assume I didn't specify properly the question since all suggested solutions didn't work for me i.e. when I tested the suggested XPath expressions in Scrapy console output was nothing. Thus, I provide more detailed information about web-site that I need to parse:

1. link to the web-site: [link to real-estate web site](http://www.lun.ua/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2)
2. screenshot of what I need to parse:

[image: screen_shot]

Comment: `sel.xpath(u'//*[text()="Некий текст"]/following-sibling::text()')` (note the `u''`) doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in non-ascii symbols and the query itself is correct?

Comment: Could you provide a sample URL or HTML snippet? It may need some use of `normalize-space()`, i.e. `sel.xpath(u'//*[normalize-space(.)="Некий текст"]/following-sibling::text()')`. And you can also try `sel.xpath(u'//*[normalize-space(.)="\u041d\u0435\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u0442\u0435\u043a\u0441\u0442"]/following-sibling::text()')`

Comment: Please, see the edited post. I will try to use encoded non-ascii symbols as you suggested.

Comment: Test your xpath queries using Firefox addon `Firepath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider declaring your encoding at the beginning of the file as `latin-1`. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for a thorough explanation as to why.

I'll be using `lxml` instead of `Scrapy` below, but the logic is the same.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from lxml import html

markup = """div class="obj-params">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col" style="min-width:50%;">
                      <p>
                         <b>Некий текст</b>" Param1_value"</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param2_name_in_russian</strong>" Param2_value</p>
                      <p>
                         <strong>Param3_name_in_russian</strong>" Param3_value"</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="obj-params-col">
                    <p>
                       <b>Param4_name_in_russian</b>Param4_value</p>
                <div class="inline-popup popup-hor left">
                   <b>Param5_name</b>
                      <a target="_blank" href="link">Param5_value</a></div></div>"""

tree = html.fromstring(markup)
pone_val = tree.xpath(u"//*[text()='Некий текст']/following-sibling::text()")

print pone_val
```

**Result:**

```
['" Param1_value"']
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Note that since this is a unicode string, the `u` at the beginning of the Xpath is necessary, same as @warwaruk's comment in your question.

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

Based on the site's markup, there's actually a better way to get the values. Again, using `lxml` and not `Scrapy` since the difference between the two here is just `.extract()` anyway. Basically, *check my XPath* for the name, room, square, and floor.

```
import requests as rq
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.lun.ua/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2"
r = rq.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)

divs = tree.xpath("//div[@class='obj-left']")

for div in divs:

    name = div.xpath("./h3/span/a/text()")[0]
    details = div.xpath(".//div[@class='obj-params-col'][1]")[0]
    room = details.xpath("./p[1]/text()[last()]")[0]
    square = details.xpath("./p[2]/text()[last()]")[0]
    floor = details.xpath("./p[3]/text()[last()]")[0]

    print name.encode("utf-8")
    print room.encode("utf-8")
    print square.encode("utf-8")
    print floor.encode("utf-8")
```

This doesn't print them out all well on my end (getting some `[Decode error - output not utf-8]`). However, I believe that encoding aside, using this approach is much better scraping practice overall.

Let us know what you think.

Comment: Checked the page. Why are you scraping using this way? There's a far safer way to do this. See edit.

Comment: Really appreciate your reply! It helped me a lot: your suggestion to use lxml and working example.

Comment: @mr.M: You're welcome. I know that it's pretty far from what you started on, but this is far safer for the set-up, especially since they don't load the HTML via JavaScript or some such anyway. :)

Comment: @Nаnashi: could you suggest some xpath tutorials? I would like to boost my knowledge of this language.

Comment: Well, you can never go wrong with [WC3's XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/). Easy enough to follow and the reference style and very concise yet clear explanations are perfect. Admittedly, I never had to read any tutorials. Most of the XPath, I learned naturally. The others like `contains`, `last()`, etc, I just learned from reading other's code. :)